# Why does counter = counter /2; have O(log(n))?

Tags: c, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I know the following code has a complexity of O(log(n)):

```
while (n>1)
{
    counter++;
    n/=2;
}
```

I understand that here, `n` is being divided in half on each iteration, meaning that if `n` was 1000 then it will take ten rounds to get out of the loop. How did this lead to O(log(n))?

Sorry for the simple question, I really tried my best to get it before I asked.

Comment: What's the log base 2 of 1000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time through the loop, you divide by 2 (roughly; this will ignore rounding since it is an asymptotic argument). So if n = N at the start, after k iterations, n=N/(2^k). To arrive at n = 1, you have to satisfy 2^k = N. That is, k = log(N).

Comment: Ah, thanks for all the answers, I guess this one sums it up.
But another stupid question, why would n = (N/2^k) after k iterations. And would it be n=(N/3^k) if we were dividing by 3 rather than 2 and so on?

Comment: If dividing by 3, then, yes, after k iterations it would be N/(3^k). For any divisor d, if after k iterations you have N/(d^k), then on iteration (k+1) you will have (N/(d^k))/d = N/(d*(d^k)) = N/(d^(k+1)). That proves the general formula by induction, since on iteration 0 you have N = N/1 = N/(d^0).

Answer (score 2):

The recurrence relation would be

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)
```

Trying to solve it using [Master's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) will give the running time of T(n) as O(log n) (similar to what you get in Binary Search).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that n is 2^x (e.g. 2^5=32, 2^10=1024 etc), so that  the counter is incremented x times within the loop.  By definition, x is a base 2 log n.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, logarithms aren't linear. In other words, they change by different amounts depending on the input. In your example, the first step takes `n` down by 500, while the fifth step reduces it by only 32. The closer you get to one, the slower `n` decreases. This "deceleration" is exactly the kind of behavior you get with a log.

Answer (score 0):

A simple hand-wavey explanation: What happens if you double n? Does the runtime double (that would be O(n))? No, the runtime increases by *only one step*. This is typical of O(log n).

[OTOH, if you squared n (say it increased from 4 to 16), then you find the number of steps double. Again, indicative of O(log n).]